# How to name components of a Pair

Tags: kotlin, tuples

Given the [Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/) `val coordinates = Pair(2, 3)`, is it possible to name each value so I can do something like `coordinates.x` to return `2`? Or is `coordinates.first` the only way to access that first value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not supported. You should write a wrapper (data) class for that purposes or you could use Kotlin destructuring declarations:

```
val (x, y) = coordinates
println("$x;$y")
```

See more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

Answer (score 12):

Another solution is to define an `object` with meaningful extensions for  `Pair<A, B>` and to bring these extensions into the context using [`with(...) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html).

```
object PointPairs {
    val <X> Pair<X, *>.x get() = first
    val <Y> Pair<*, Y>.y get() = second
}
```

And the usage:

```
val point = Pair(2, 3)

with(PointPairs) {
    println(point.x)
}
```

This allows you to have several sets of extensions for the same type and to use each where appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

The definition of `Pair` in the Kotlin stdlib is as follows:

```
public data class Pair<out A, out B>(
    public val first: A,
    public val second: B
) : Serializable
```

So, if you have an instance `p` of type `Pair`, you can access the first property only as `p.first`. However, you can use a [Destructuring Declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations) like this:

```
val (x, y) = p
```

This is made possible because `Pair` is a [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes). Every argument of the primary constructor of a data class gets a `componentX()` method, where `X` is the index of the parameter. So the above call can be expressed like this:

```
val x = p.component1()
val y = p.component2()
```

This makes it absolutely independent from the actual name of the parameter.

If you, however, want to be able to write `p.x`, you'll have to go ahead and create your own data class (or use a library):

```
data class Point(val x : Double, val y : Double)
```

Answer (score 9):

I want to propose an alternative, which should be applied if the renaming is desired only in a certain scope.

You can create a simple extension higher-order function enabling the naming in a scope, passed as a lambda-argument:

```
fun <F, S> Pair<F, S>.named(block: (F, S) -> Unit) = block(first, second)
```

Now, a `Pair` can be called with a lambda, which is invoked with its components that are name-able on caller-site:

```
val pair = Pair(2, 3)
pair.named { x, y ->
    println("my pair: ($x,$y)")
}
```

It's even possible to apply the [`invoke` convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke):

```
operator fun<F, S> Pair<F, S>.invoke(block: (F, S) -> Unit) = block(first, second)
```

Now, the `Pair` can be invoked directly:

```
val pair = Pair(2, 3)
pair { x, y ->
    println("my pair: ($x,$y)")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Kotlin documetation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#standard-data-classes) says:

> The standard library provides Pair and Triple. In most cases, though,
>   named data classes are a better design choice, because they make the
>   code more readable by providing meaningful names for properties.

Since `Pair` is final you can unfortunately not inherit from it, but I would suggest to create a dedicated class `Point`:

```
data class Point<T>(val x: T, val y: T)
```

to represent a point. This way wherever you use it you are always forced to access it using the meaningful names.

Use it:

```
val myPoint = Point(1.0, 2.0)
println("This is the horizontal coordinate: ${myPoint.x}")
```

Answer (score 4):

another thing i enjoy doing here to help code readability, is to use typealias (or more recently inline classes but still experimental at this time)

so you could do this:

```
typealias Radius = Double?
typealias Area= Float
```

then do:  `Pair<Area,Radius>`
so its much more readable, but for access description i  would do data class.

you could take it one step further:

```
typealias  DimensionsPair = Pair<Area,Radius>
```

note that i think inline class here would bring better type safety.

Comment: Nice approach as it provide a bit more clear self documentation to code. Only drawback is that you still have to use the `.first` and `.second` to access each pair part.

Comment: No. I never do that. Instead you can destruct the pair. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133398/835883